# fitting Poisson distribution to data in python

Tags: python, distribution

I have data distribution that I want to fit Poisson distribution to it. my data looks like that:

[image: data]

I try to fit :

```
 mu = herd_size["COW_NUM"].mean() 
ax=sns.displot(data=herd_size["COW_NUM"], kde=True)
ax.set(xlabel='Size',title='Herd size distribution & poisson distribution')
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 2000, 80), [st.poisson.pmf(np.arange(i, i+80), mu).sum()*len(herd_size["COW_NUM"])
                                  for i in np.arange(0, 2000, 80)], color='red')
#every bin contain approximatly 80 observes
plt.show()
```

but I get something not at the same scale:

[image: data with Poisson fit]

**UPDATE**
I try to apply negative binom distribution with the code:

```
n=len(herd_size["COW_NUM"])
p =herd_size["COW_NUM"].mean()/(herd_size["COW_NUM"].mean()+2) 
ax=sns.displot(data=herd_size["COW_NUM"], kde=True)
ax.set(xlabel='Size',title='Herd size distribution & geometry distribution')
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 2000, 80), [st.nbinom.pmf(np.arange(i, i+80), n,p).sum()*len(herd_size["COW_NUM"])
                                  for i in np.arange(0, 2000, 80)], color='red')
#every bin contain approximatly 80 observes
plt.show()
```

but I got this:
[nbinom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS4z5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plot is (at least approximately) correct, the problem is with modeling your data as Poisson.  As lambda grows large the Poisson looks more and more like a normal distribution — see [this plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#/media/File:Poisson_pmf.svg) from Wikipedia.  A Poisson distribution has its variance equal to its mean, so with a mean of around ~240 you have a standard deviation of ~15.5.  The net result is that outcomes for a Poisson(240) should overwhelmingly fall between 210 and 270, which is what your red plot shows.  Try fitting a different distribution to your data.

---

I just spotted StupidWolf's answer.  Other than using a mean of 200 rather than 240, his histogram shows the same behavior described above.

Comment: Thank you. do you have any idea which distribution could fit ?

Comment: @myh I would start with something simple, only copule of parameter - e.g. Negative Binomial migh twork

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Other possibilities might be exponential or gamma distributions if you're willing to view the range [1,2000] as effectively continuous, i.e., rounding to the nearest integer won't cause problems.

Comment: @myh For future modeling, a first-order check on whether Poisson is reasonable is whether the data are non-negative integers and whether the mean and variance are approximately the same.

Comment: @myh - I spent a few minutes playing around in my stats package of choice, and a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with a shape parameter k around 1.4 looks an awful lot like your data.

Comment: yes @pjs, you are right.. the data is overdispersed, a gamma or negative binomial will work

Answer (score 3):

For what you need to plot, might be easier to provide the bins to make your histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import poisson

herd_size = pd.DataFrame({'COW_NUM':np.random.poisson(200,2000)})
binwidth = 10
xstart = 150
xend = 280
bins = np.arange(xstart,xend,binwidth)

o = sns.histplot(data=herd_size["COW_NUM"], kde=True,bins = bins)
```

Then calculate your mean and total number:

```
mu = herd_size["COW_NUM"].mean() 
n = len(herd_size)
```

The expected frequency is the difference of the start and end of cdf on your left and right intervals:

```
plt.plot(bins + binwidth/2 , n*(poisson.cdf(bins+binwidth,mu) - poisson.cdf(bins,mu)), color='red')
```

[image]

Your data is overdispersed, because for a poisson you don't expect data to be so spread. so what you need to do is to use a gamma or a negative binomial to fit it, for example:

```
from scipy.stats import nbinom
herd_size = pd.DataFrame({'COW_NUM':nbinom.rvs(n=2,p=0.1,loc=240,size=2000)})
binwidth = 50
xstart = 0
xend = 2000
bins = np.arange(xstart,xend,binwidth)

herd_size = pd.DataFrame({'COW_NUM':nbinom.rvs(n=1,p=0.004,size=2000)})

Var = herd_size["COW_NUM"].var()
mu = herd_size["COW_NUM"].mean()
p =  (mu/Var)
r = mu**2 / (Var-mu)
n = len(herd_size)

o = sns.histplot(data=herd_size["COW_NUM"], kde=True,bins=bins)

plt.plot(bins + binwidth/2 , 
         n*(nbinom.cdf(bins+binwidth,r,p) - nbinom.cdf(bins,r,p)), 
         color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: when I copy that code to my data, I get the same plot as I got before(which post on the question)

Comment: your data does not fit a poisson. you need to use something to accounts for overdispersion. for example a negative binomial. ok i post an edit

Comment: can you try to show me how negative binomial fit the data? the plot is again seem to be wrong , probably I did something wrong.

Comment: I think the gamma does a better job of representing the values at the low end, where there's a small upwards blip on the histogram.

Comment: Since we haven't seen the original dataset I can't estimate the parameterization from data, but check out the plot from `herd_size = pd.DataFrame({'COW_NUM':gamma.rvs(a = 1.2, scale = 300, size = 6500)})`